# Spring 5 Google OAuth2 needs https redirect URL, not http

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I have a hosted site with Apache httpd (ports 80 and 443) and Wildfly 15 (port 8080). My web server is set up to handle http and https and it's set up to communicate with Wildfly using these commands

```
ProxyPass        / http://myhost.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://myhost.com:8080/
```

I have a Java 11 Spring 5 app deployed to Wildfly as a WAR file. It's set up to use Google OAuth so that users can authenticate on my app. I'm trying to use some YouTube APIs that require a special "scope" which means having only https in my list of "Authorized redirect URIs". However, I need to have "http://myhost.com:8080/login/oauth2/code/google" in that list right now in order for users to log in successfully, which violates what the YouTube API needs.

I understand why it has "http" and "8080" in that URI, because the request is coming from my application deployed in Wildfly. But I need to change it to  "https://myhost.com/login/oauth2/code/google".

How do I do that?

Below are some further configurations, but they don't seem to do enough.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration
{
  @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri}")
  private String             redirectUri;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
    HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()//

    .authorizeRequests()//
    .antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated()//
    .antMatchers("/api/**", "/login/**").permitAll()// for redirectUri
    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()//
    .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()//

    .and()//
    .sessionManagement()//
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)

    .and()//
    .userDetailsService(userDetailsManager())//
    .oauth2Login()// because we need to authorize our users, not just be a web client
    //.oauth2Client()// not this
    .redirectionEndpoint().baseUri(this.redirectUri)//
    .and()//
     .clientRegistrationRepository(this.securityService.getClientRegistrationRepository())//
    .authorizedClientService(this.securityService.getAuthorizedClientService())//
    .loginPage(SecurityController.LOGIN_PAGE_MAPPING)//
    .defaultSuccessUrl(loginSuccessUrl)//
    //.successHandler(this.loginSuccessHandler)//
    .failureUrl("/login-failure-page")//

    .and()//
    .logout()//
    .clearAuthentication(true)//
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)//
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")//
    .logoutSuccessUrl(SecurityController.LOGOUT_PAGE_MAPPING).permitAll()

    // Gotta get back to the correct port after login.
    .and()//
    .requestCache().requestCache(requestCache()); // port mapper here

    // For Firefox and h2-console
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri=https://myhost.com/login/oauth2/code/google
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirectUri=https://myhost.com/login/oauth2/code/google
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.preEstablishedRedirectUri=https://myhost.com/login/oauth2/code/google
spring.security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
```

I also have this defined for CORS

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer()
{
  return new WebMvcConfigurer()
  {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(
      CorsRegistry registry)
    {
      registry.addMapping("/**")//
        .allowedOrigins(/*"http://myhost.com:8080",*/ "https://myhost.com",
            "https://myhost.com:8080")//
        .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: It is a very bad idea to disable CSRF protection with `oauth2Login` enabled: the requests to your app are authorized with session cookies, which makes it vulnerable to CSRF attacks

Comment: If I do that, then I get "CORS Missing Allow Origin / Invalid CORS request" when trying to run the JavaScript on my site.

Comment: CSRF and CORS are different security mechanisms solving different threats. Activating CSRF protection shouldn't cause CORS issues, you must have changed several things at once.

Comment: yeah, there was something else that was causing that. Found and fixed that. Still need help on the main problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can serve your Spring Boot application with SSL by using the `server.ssl` properties.

If you don't have a certificate for `myhost.com` already (on your development environment for instance), you might find what I host [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/self-signed-certificate-generation) useful to generate a self-signed SSL certificate and add it to your JDKs / JREs `cacerts` file. You'll also find instructions to add this certificate to your OS trusted root certificates.

If you're working with servlet apps, I suggest that you use [any port but 8080](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12307) when using https.

### Follow-up from comments

The option above allows to serve `https://myhost.com:8080` instead of `http://myhost.com:8080` (but as mentioned above, because of historical reasons, using `https://myhost.com:8443` in servlet apps would be much easier).

If you don't want the traffic to your Spring app to be secured and want to keep `http://myhost.com:8080`, then you have to configure the authorization code redirection URI to `https://myhost.com/login/oauth2/code/google`, as you're trying to do in properties. The thing is, as you are providing only part of your conf, we can't spot why this is not working.

##### Easy solution

The configuration you expose is quite messy and unsafe (for instance, applications with OAuth2 login are exposed to CSRF attacks, so it's a big mistake to disable CSRF protection). With [this starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#oidc-starter) I wrote, your conf could be as simple as:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

```yaml
oauth2-redirect-socket: https://myhost.com
oauth2-issuer: https://accounts.google.com
oauth2-client-id: change-me.apps.googleusercontent.com
oauth2-client-secret: change-me

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oauth2:
            issuer-uri: ${oauth2-issuer}
        registration:
          authorization-code:
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: ${oauth2-client-id}
            client-secret: ${oauth2-client-secret}
            provider: oauth2
            scope:
            - openid
            - profile
            - email
            - offline_access

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${oauth2-issuer}
          # skipping issuer configuration which is not used in your case
        client:
          # this forces to build redirect URIs pointing to the SSL gateway
          client-uri: ${oauth2-redirect-socket}
          security-matchers:
          - /**
          permit-all:
          # what is not listed below requires requests to be authorized
          - /login/**
          - /oauth2/**
          - /
          cors:
          - path: "/**"
            allowed-origin-patterns:
            - ${oauth2-redirect-socket}
```

If you don't want to use "my" starter, please refer to [this paragraph of the README](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#drawbacks). It contains links to tutorials for writing the security conf yourself.

Comment: I have a SSL cert for Apache. The https is first coming through Apache on port 443 and then the requests are passed on to Wildfly.

Comment: then why don't you configure your spring OAuth2 client  to give a callback URI pointing to the https Apache server instead of itself?

Comment: That's exactly what I need help with. I've been trying to do that, but haven't found the magic formula to do so. It's why I added my security config to the question.

Comment: You mean something like what is in the [second paragraph of the OAuth2 login manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html#oauth2login-sample-redirect-uri) ?

Comment: Does the first line in the application.properties file excerpt above do what they say in that second paragraph? If so, then yes, I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: I've shown everyone my code, which I got from scouring the web already. It's not working. I'm looking for someone to point to a spot(s) in my code and say "that's not right, here's the right thing."

Comment: Your configuration is messy and the snippets you provide are incomplete. For instance, it references `this.redirectUri`, but we have no idea how this is set. Also you are using very deprecated properties and some are defined in double. Do some cleanup.

Comment: I've added some more config code. Also, I'm new to Spring Security, and I cobbled this up from whatever web pages I could find, trying to use the latest. However, I never found a page for, say, Spring Security 5 specifically, mentioning which things are deprecated and which things are new. If you know of such a page, please let me know.

Comment: I have [a set of tutorials on Github](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials), but all are written with Spring Boot 3 / Security 6

Answer (score 1):

@ch4mp gave me the information I needed, but I'm going to put here the things I had to do to get it working. First, I hadn't considered making Wildfly secure, but you can and I did. I had my hosting company install the certs from my Apache server to Wildfly.

I then changed my Apache config file to use this:

```
ProxyPass        / https://hostname.com:8443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://hostname.com:8443/
```

but an additional change was adding the following, because without it, nothing worked.

```
SSLProxyEngine on
```

I still have OAuth2 security config to clean up, but ch4mp gave me a lot to work with. I view that as a secondary problem to getting the Oauth2 redirect URI to use https instead of http.